# requestAnimationFrame seems to update variables after cancelAnimationFrame is called

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to animate a camera rotation using MapBoxGL, while providing the option to pause the rotation and restart the rotation with a checkbox callback.  The 'pause'/'stop' rotation works fine, but the 'restart' seems to pick up the animation where the it should have been if it was never paused, as opposed to picking up where the animation stopped.

```
var animation;

function rotateCamera(timestamp) {
    map.rotateTo((timestamp / 600) % 360, {duration: 0});
    animation = requestAnimationFrame(rotateCamera);
}
```

When the map loads, the animation is called with:

```
animation = rotateCamera(0);
```

The callback looks like this:

```
d3.selectAll("input[name='camerarotation-selection']").on("change", function() {
    if (d3.select("input[name='selection']").property("checked")) {
        rotateCamera(map.getBearing());
    } else {
        cancelAnimationFrame(animation);
    }
});
```

If I `console.log` the timestamp var inside the `rotateCamera` function, I can see that despite the `cancelAnimationFrame` call, it continues to be incremented.  I have tried declaring `animation` to be undefined upon a restart, and that doesn't seem to work either.  I'm stumped!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE]. Are you saying that your `rotateCamera` loop is still running once you changed the input value? Can you see this behavior in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j01r9yb2/)?

Comment: @Kaiido wow yeah that's whats going on.  thanks, you are much better at this than I am.  so yeah in my example, the `map.rotateTo()` stops running but the `timestamp` inside keeps incrementing, just like in your fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timestamp passed to the callback of `requestAnimationFrame` is an DOMHighResTimestamp, similar to the one returned by [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now). 
This timestamp indicates the number of milliseconds that elapsed since the beginning of the current document's lifetime (well it can be [a bit more complicated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp#The_time_origin)) when the callbacks execution started.

So even when no *requestAnimationFrame* loop is running, this timestamp indeed increments, just like `Date.now()` also does.

```js
let animation = 0;
inp.onchange = e => {
  if (inp.checked) start();
  else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animation);
  }
};

function start(timestamp) {
  _log.textContent = timestamp;
  animation = requestAnimationFrame(start);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="inp">
<pre id="_log"></pre>
```

In your code, you will probably want to only keep the time that elapsed since last frame. To do so, you can simply save `timestamp` in a variable that is globally available, and then in your callback do

```
var elapsed = timestamp - last_frame;
last_frame = timestamp;
```

And remember to also take care of the resume case, where `timestamp` will be undefined and `elapsed` should be reset.

---

---

Now, I'd like to point out that your description of the problem could also indicate an other problem entirely: you could have more than a single loop running simultaneously.

Since you are using a single `animation`  variable to hold the frame_id (used by cancelAnimationFrame), if you do call `rotateCamera` while a loop is already running, the first frame_ids will get lost, and their rAF loop will indeed continue.

```js
let common_id = 0; // OP's `animation` variable
let first_id = 0;
let second_id = 0;

function loop1(timestamp) {
  common_id = first_id = requestAnimationFrame(loop1);
  log_1.textContent = "loop 1: " + timestamp;
}

function loop2(timestamp) {
  common_id = second_id = requestAnimationFrame(loop2);
  log_2.textContent = "loop 2: " + timestamp;
}

btn.onclick = e => {
  console.log("first loop's id", first_id);
  console.log("second loop's id", second_id);
  console.log('clearing common_id', common_id);
  cancelAnimationFrame(common_id);
}

loop1();
loop2();
```

```html
<button id="btn">stop the loop</button>

<pre id="log_1"></pre>
<pre id="log_2"></pre>
```

I think it is possible in your code, since `input[name='camerarotation-selection']` could change multiple times, when `input[name='selection']` had not chnaged, or even since `input[name='camerarotation-selection']` could be multiple elements.

To avoid that, you could keep a semaphore variable allowing you to know if the loop is running or not, and to only start it when it's not. 
Or you could even get rid entirely of `cancelAnimationFrame` by using only one semaphore, and exiting early in the rAF callback:

```js
let stopped = true;

function loop(timestamp) {
  if (stopped) return; // exit early
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  log.textContent = timestamp;
}
// you can click it several times
btn_start.onclick = e => {
  if (stopped === true) { // only if not running yet
    stopped = false;
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
}
btn_stop.onclick = e => {
  stopped = true; // deal only with the semaphore
};

btn_switch.onclick = e => {
  stopped = !stopped;
  if (stopped === false) { // we were paused
    // start again
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_start">start the loop</button>
<button id="btn_stop">stop the loop</button>
<button id="btn_switch">switch the loop</button>

<pre id="log"></pre>
```

Comment: thanks, i should have read the page about the `DOMHighResTimeStamp` type when i read the documentation.  the elapsed variable solution is also above and beyond what i deserve and helps me a lot.  thanks for helping me out.